# New laptop: what would be more efficient? SSD hard-drive or 16 GB RAM?

Tags: windows-8, hard-drive, laptop, memory, vmware-workstation

I plan to purchase a new laptop (Dell) and my budget allows me to choose one of the following:

- SSD hard-drive, 128 GB, for running Windows 8 OS (instead of 500GB hard-drive 5400 RPM)
- (or) 16 GB RAM (instead of 8 GB RAM).

What do you think could be more important if I have to run VMware machine a few times a week for demos?

THANK YOU

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SSD, would make more of a difference in general use.  8gb is enough, and 16gb would only be useful if you were running multiple vm's at the same time but with a slow disk that would be painful.

I would shop further around as well, as I recently got a 256b ssd from [Crucial](http://www.crucial.com/eu/store/ssd.aspx).

Comment: I'm going along with cjb110 here. An SSD is the better choice over RAM, considered that you only use the VMWare machines to demo. Do note that 128GB of space on an SSD is not a whole lot, especially if you run 2 or more OS's on it (I'm counting the VMWare images) You should keep in mind that for an SSD to work fast and reliable, you should have at least 25% free space available all the time. Beyond this point, an SSD will become slow quickly, and once ahead of this point, it may stay slow (due to how TRIM works)

Answer (score 1):

It really depends on what you are doing

Scenario 1: 
You have a bunch of data to store on your computer, want to be able to run programs fast, but aren't particularly concerned about the speed at which they open (or the speed at which the computer turns on.) You also tend to run many programs at once.
**go with the 16 gb of ram. This will ensure top notch system performance in terms of program speed. You also have 500 gb of storage instead of 128.**

Scenario 2: 
You want your computer to turn on super fast, don't have that many files to store, but often use programs that are complex and use multiple files at once that you want to work fast. 
**Go with the SSD. Since you are more concerned with hdd access times, this is definitely the way to go. 8gb of ram is still top of the line for modern computers.**

personally, if given the choice, I would choose the 16 gb of ram. This is because I use many programs at once and really need the extra space a spinning drive provides. 
I have a computer with a 1 TB 5400 rmp drive and I have rarely noticed computer lag due to the hard drive. When I do it is usually because I am copying files and running a virus scan at the same time.

In case you ever want the temporary performance of an ssd, you can use SoftPerfect Ram Disk to create a ram drive with your extra ram.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

i think you should go for Second option 16 GB RAM, SSD Drive is faster than 5400 rpm hard drive but if you choose 16 GB ram with 5400 rpm  hard drive it would be good for running VMware machine.